# Tensorflow multiply broadcasting (convolution before summation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, filter, convolution

I am looking for a tensor flow API which takes a filter and go through a tensor and multiply them and gives me a vector for each element.

Let's make it more clear. I have 2D matrix of gray scale image. I have a 2D filter (e.g. 3x3), I am going to roll my filter across the image and get a 9-length vector for each pixel such that each vector's element is corresponding filter element and pixel neighbor multiplication. In other words, I need the result of conv2d before summation. The summation of this vector would be the convolution of filter and corresponding pixel.

I can't find any standard API for this operation. I can write a code looping over the elements, but it is not efficient. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: That sounds like a 1x1 filter with 9 times the output channel number, doesn't it? You just have to carefully rearrange them back so that they correspond to the correct pixels...

Comment: Yes, You can see it as 9 1x1 filters applying on each element of the window. The problem is: the operation is not fast and I need to shift the tensor and keep track of what's going on. The speed part is more important to me. I can write a code in numpy version, but it runs on CPU. I'm thinking of tensorflow to take advantage of GPU processing.

Comment: @Richard_wth your comment was useful and helped me to think about using tf.maip.roll(), tf.pad(), and tf.slice(). This way is faster than my original thought but the question is if they work with dynamic shape?